# R: Using read.table to import a column with a different delimiter than other columns?

Tags: r, read.table

I have a txt file of chess games from http://chess-research-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. The first 8 lines of the file are as follows:

```
# #
# datetime 2013-08-10 22:32:16.640552
# program programs/formats/pgn_to_filtered_very_basic_format_plus_info_filtering_info.py
# filein original_data/scidbase/all.pgn
# 1.t 2.date 3.result 4.welo 5.belo 6.len 7.date_c 8.resu_c 9.welo_c 10.belo_c 11.edate_c 12.setup 13.fen 14.resu2_c 15.oyrange 16.bad_len 17.game...
1 2000.03.14 1-0 2851 None 67 date_false result_false welo_false belo_true edate_true setup_false fen_false result2_false oyrange_false blen_false ### W1.d4 B1.d5 W2.c4 B2.e6 W3.Nc3 B3.Nf6 W4.cxd5 B4.exd5 W5.Bg5 B5.Be7 W6.e3 B6.Ne4 W7.Bxe7 B7.Nxc3 W8.Bxd8 B8.Nxd1 W9.Bxc7 B9.Nxb2 W10.Rb1 B10.Nc4 W11.Bxc4 B11.dxc4 W12.Ne2 B12.O-O W13.Nc3 B13.b6 W14.d5 B14.Na6 W15.Bd6 B15.Rd8 W16.Ba3 B16.Bb7 W17.e4 B17.f6 W18.Ke2 B18.Nc7 W19.Rhd1 B19.Ba6 W20.Ke3 B20.Kf7 W21.g4 B21.g5 W22.h4 B22.h6 W23.Rh1 B23.Re8 W24.f3 B24.Bb7 W25.hxg5 B25.fxg5 W26.d6 B26.Nd5+ W27.Nxd5 B27.Bxd5 W28.Rxh6 B28.c3 W29.d7 B29.Re6 W30.Rh7+ B30.Kg8 W31.Rbh1 B31.Bc6 W32.Rh8+ B32.Kf7 W33.Rxa8 B33.Bxd7 W34.Rh7+
2 2000.03.14 1-0 2851 None 53 date_false result_false welo_false belo_true edate_true setup_false fen_false result2_false oyrange_false blen_false ### W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.exd5 B2.Qxd5 W3.Nc3 B3.Qa5 W4.d4 B4.Nf6 W5.Nf3 B5.c6 W6.Ne5 B6.Bf5 W7.g4 B7.Be4 W8.f3 B8.Bd5 W9.a3 B9.Nbd7 W10.Be3 B10.Nxe5 W11.dxe5 B11.Nxg4 W12.Bd4 B12.e6 W13.b4 B13.Qd8 W14.Nxd5 B14.Qxd5 W15.c4 B15.Ne3 W16.cxd5 B16.Nxd1 W17.dxc6 B17.bxc6 W18.Rxd1 B18.Be7 W19.Ba6 B19.O-O W20.Ke2 B20.Rab8 W21.Rc1 B21.Rfd8 W22.Rhd1 B22.c5 W23.Bxc5 B23.Rxd1 W24.Rxd1 B24.Bxc5 W25.bxc5 B25.g6 W26.c6 B26.Rb2+ W27.Rd2
3 1999.11.20 1-0 2851 None 57 date_false result_false welo_false belo_true edate_false setup_false fen_false result2_false oyrange_false blen_false ### W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nc6 W3.Bc4 B3.Bc5 W4.c3 B4.Nf6 W5.d3 B5.d6 W6.Bb3 B6.O-O W7.Nbd2 B7.Be6 W8.O-O B8.Qd7 W9.Re1 B9.Rfe8 W10.Nf1 B10.Ne7 W11.Ng3 B11.Bg4 W12.h3 B12.Be6 W13.Bg5 B13.Kh8 W14.Bxf6 B14.gxf6 W15.d4 B15.exd4 W16.cxd4 B16.Bb4 W17.Re3 B17.Rg8 W18.d5 B18.Bxh3 W19.Qd4 B19.Rg6 W20.Qxb4 B20.c5 W21.Qc3 B21.Bg4 W22.Bc2 B22.Rh6 W23.Nh2 B23.b5 W24.b4 B24.Rc8 W25.Bd3 B25.c4 W26.Bc2 B26.Bh5 W27.Nxh5 B27.Rxh5 W28.Qxf6+ B28.Kg8 W29.Bd1
```

There are 17 columns, the first 16 showing some information about each game, and the 17th being the game moves. This 17th column is different to the others as it starts after ###, and also has a space after each move. How should `read.table()` (or a similar function) by used so that the game moves are properly imported into their own column?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790053/r-using-read-table-does-not-import-everything) ?

Comment: If I use `comment.char = ""` so the 17th column is read I still have the issue that the 17th column (with the game moves) has spaces, unlike the other columns, and get the error "more columns than column names"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting column *(1 to 16)* and *(17)* separately:

**If reading from file, `text_file.txt`:**

```
# extracting columns 1 to 16 and empty column for 17
df <- read.table(file = 'text_file.txt',  sep = " ")
n <- nrow(df)

# split string on both " ### " and "\n"  
line = readLines('text_file.txt')
str = grep(line, value=TRUE, pattern = "###")
chr_vec <- unlist(strsplit(x = str, split = " ### |\n"))

# indices for column 17 elements in chr_vec
idx_17 <- 2*(1:n) 
df['V17'] <- chr_vec[idx_17]
```

**If reading from string `str`:**

```
# extracting columns 1 to 16 and empty column for 17
df <- read.table(text = str,  sep = " ", header = TRUE)
n <- nrow(df)

# split string on both " ### " and "\n"  
chr_vec <- unlist(strsplit(x = str, split = " ### |\n"))

# indices for column 17 elements in chr_vec
idx_17 <- 2*(1:n) + 1 
df['X17.game...'] <- chr_vec[idx_17]
```

**Data:**

```
str <- "1.t 2.date 3.result 4.welo 5.belo 6.len 7.date_c 8.resu_c 9.welo_c 10.belo_c 11.edate_c 12.setup 13.fen 14.resu2_c 15.oyrange 16.bad_len 17.game...
1 2000.03.14 1-0 2851 None 67 date_false result_false welo_false belo_true edate_true setup_false fen_false result2_false oyrange_false blen_false ### W1.d4 B1.d5 W2.c4 B2.e6 W3.Nc3 B3.Nf6 W4.cxd5 B4.exd5 W5.Bg5 B5.Be7 W6.e3 B6.Ne4 W7.Bxe7 B7.Nxc3 W8.Bxd8 B8.Nxd1 W9.Bxc7 B9.Nxb2 W10.Rb1 B10.Nc4 W11.Bxc4 B11.dxc4 W12.Ne2 B12.O-O W13.Nc3 B13.b6 W14.d5 B14.Na6 W15.Bd6 B15.Rd8 W16.Ba3 B16.Bb7 W17.e4 B17.f6 W18.Ke2 B18.Nc7 W19.Rhd1 B19.Ba6 W20.Ke3 B20.Kf7 W21.g4 B21.g5 W22.h4 B22.h6 W23.Rh1 B23.Re8 W24.f3 B24.Bb7 W25.hxg5 B25.fxg5 W26.d6 B26.Nd5+ W27.Nxd5 B27.Bxd5 W28.Rxh6 B28.c3 W29.d7 B29.Re6 W30.Rh7+ B30.Kg8 W31.Rbh1 B31.Bc6 W32.Rh8+ B32.Kf7 W33.Rxa8 B33.Bxd7 W34.Rh7+
2 2000.03.14 1-0 2851 None 53 date_false result_false welo_false belo_true edate_true setup_false fen_false result2_false oyrange_false blen_false ### W1.e4 B1.d5 W2.exd5 B2.Qxd5 W3.Nc3 B3.Qa5 W4.d4 B4.Nf6 W5.Nf3 B5.c6 W6.Ne5 B6.Bf5 W7.g4 B7.Be4 W8.f3 B8.Bd5 W9.a3 B9.Nbd7 W10.Be3 B10.Nxe5 W11.dxe5 B11.Nxg4 W12.Bd4 B12.e6 W13.b4 B13.Qd8 W14.Nxd5 B14.Qxd5 W15.c4 B15.Ne3 W16.cxd5 B16.Nxd1 W17.dxc6 B17.bxc6 W18.Rxd1 B18.Be7 W19.Ba6 B19.O-O W20.Ke2 B20.Rab8 W21.Rc1 B21.Rfd8 W22.Rhd1 B22.c5 W23.Bxc5 B23.Rxd1 W24.Rxd1 B24.Bxc5 W25.bxc5 B25.g6 W26.c6 B26.Rb2+ W27.Rd2
3 1999.11.20 1-0 2851 None 57 date_false result_false welo_false belo_true edate_false setup_false fen_false result2_false oyrange_false blen_false ### W1.e4 B1.e5 W2.Nf3 B2.Nc6 W3.Bc4 B3.Bc5 W4.c3 B4.Nf6 W5.d3 B5.d6 W6.Bb3 B6.O-O W7.Nbd2 B7.Be6 W8.O-O B8.Qd7 W9.Re1 B9.Rfe8 W10.Nf1 B10.Ne7 W11.Ng3 B11.Bg4 W12.h3 B12.Be6 W13.Bg5 B13.Kh8 W14.Bxf6 B14.gxf6 W15.d4 B15.exd4 W16.cxd4 B16.Bb4 W17.Re3 B17.Rg8 W18.d5 B18.Bxh3 W19.Qd4 B19.Rg6 W20.Qxb4 B20.c5 W21.Qc3 B21.Bg4 W22.Bc2 B22.Rh6 W23.Nh2 B23.b5 W24.b4 B24.Rc8 W25.Bd3 B25.c4 W26.Bc2 B26.Bh5 W27.Nxh5 B27.Rxh5 W28.Qxf6+ B28.Kg8 W29.Bd1"
```